# Passover duplicates on Shabbat 2 years in a row

Tags: passover, calendar

Passover fell this year on Shabbat which is rare.  It also fell last year on Shabbat.  Two years in a row is incredibly rare.  The question is in two parts: when has this duplication taken place before?  When will the duplication of two years in a row take place again?

Comment: How have you tried finding the answer yourself? Did you look at a Jewish calendar program?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? This seems like a pretty arbitrary statistic to be interested in.

Comment: Rob, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question!
If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 
I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Answer (score 3):

5751,5752

The previous time

The next time

5778,5779 (if we do not start deciding months by the court)

---

This time

5775,5776

Answer (score 3):

The years are 353, 354, 355, (nonleap) and 383, 384, 385 years (leap). divide by seven and the remainder shows how many days in the week each day in the year will have been moved from the previous year. Here is the modulo 7 list for the possible years.

```
353 % 7 = 3
354 % 7 = 4
355 % 7 = 5
383 % 7 = 5
384 % 7 = 6
385 % 7 = 0
```

This year we have 385 days which is evenly divisible by 7 so that the days are the same day of the week as 385 days ago (the previous year). Note that this starts at Pesach because Adar Sheni caused the extra month to be added and pushed Pesach to start on Shabbos. As a result, every day from Pesach to the end of Kislev will always be the same day of the week as the previous year. Teves may cause a difference because of the malei/chaseir difference. I discuss this with respect to Rosh Hashana at [Why four out of five years (5771 - 5775) start on Thursday - Friday](http://sabbahillel.blogspot.com/2010/09/why-four-out-of-five-years-5771-5775.html). Note that the discussion is based on Rosh Hashanah as that starts the year.

Comment: Had a quick scan at the linked blog. Interesting. The "molad zaken" rule is interesting, and its source as mentioned in Mas. Rosh Hashannah is quite detailed. It has to do with the New Moon length between abavel and Eretz Yisra'el, actually. Art Scroll Rosh Hashanna at the appendix explains this fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

@hazoriz's answer provides specific years. Here, I will explain the general scenario.

There are 6 lengths of Judaic years:

Chaser or "missing" - 353 days for regular and 383 days for leap years

Kesidrah - "In order" - 354 days for regular and 384 for leap years

Maleh - "Full" - 355 days for a regular and 385 for leap years

I won't delve into how the length of the year is determined. That's a rather long explanation. If you'f liuke to knwo, comment (ping) and I'll get you alink to my google drive where I discuss this.

In brief, any maleh leap year causes a repetition of the days of the week for holidays in the previous year. There seems to be no pattern as to how often this scenario occurs, but from what I have checked in the past approx. 40 years, this pattern seems to occur on average every 4 to 5 years.

As far as Pesach is concerned, only Tuesday, Thursday and Shabbat can be repeated in two consecutive years. Sunday is never repeated. Since Pesach is most likely to occur on Tuesday, the Tuesday repetition tends to be the most common.